# Sphinx + Doxygen + Breathe: How do I get a documentation like the one of Google's Ceres Solver?

Tags: c++, python-sphinx, doxygen

I'm working on a C++ project and really fell in love with the Sphinx documentation build system. I managed to setup Doxygen and Breathe to produce and provide the C++ descriptions to Sphinx.

I can't figure out how Google's Ceres Solver documentation was done. Their [API reference](http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_modeling.html#_CPPv2N5ceres12CostFunctionE) for example contains class names followed by lots of text, sometimes even with code block examples as shown in the previous link. **Is there a way to write Doxygen documentation inside the source files and achieve this?**

Another example is [this class documentation](http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_modeling.html#_CPPv2N5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionE), which has around two pages of text. I somehow doubt that all this text is located in the source files as Doxygen comments. I have the feeling that all the extra text has been written in the restructured text sources for the documentation and nothing in the c++ source files. But then what is the point of using doxygen and breathe...

Or asked differently, **where should I put high-level information about the code**? I mean I can document `class1` and `class2` in their sources, but somewhere I need to explain how both of them interact and are used together. This is what the documentation of the Ceres Solver does so nicely in my opinion.

Alternatively you could point me to a C++ project with the Sphinx + Doxygen + Breathe pipeline and open source documentation. Then I can see for myself how to do these things. Unfortunately I don't know about any project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed the github link for the Ceres Solver. There the sources of the documentation can be found. I'm a bit disappointed, because the complete documentation is written in the Restructured Text source files and NOT inside the c++ code. Basically they reference the class name with `.. class:: className` and then add ReST markdown for informative text, example code blocks etc. One example is given in ["Modeling Non-linear Least Squares"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/master/docs/source/nnls_modeling.rst)